# Flutter, How to refresh the last page state on Navigator.pop

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, back

I have to pages, p1 and p2. When you launch the app, you're on p1 and can open p2. I want that when you leave p2 with the back button, the p1 state refresh (like calling again initState() without creating a new route with Navigator.push or using WillPopScope).

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can call a method to refresh your first page state after the second screen is popped.

p1:

```
refreshState() {
  // change your state to refresh the screen
}

Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => p2()),).then((res) => refreshPage());
```

p2:

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

When you push a new page you can have its pop callback.

```
// If you want to get particular type of data arguments, then can add it with MaterialPageRoute<Data_Type_Value_You_Want_In_Return>
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute<bool>(builder: (context) => page2()),).then((bool res) {
      // check here if you got your data or not
      if(res!=null && res==true){
        refreshPage();
      }
    });
```

In your next screen

```
// Let say if i want to pass bool value arguments then pass it inside pop method.
Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
```

So, in flutter you can pass get pop callback as well as arguments.

Comment: what is refreshPage and how to implement it?

Comment: @MohitC refreshPage() is your custom block of code or whatever your code logic.